# Soft latch on/off button simulation

Tags: simulation, latch, pmos, pspice

I am trying to simulated in pspice a soft latch on/off circuit but it is not working as expected, even if I double check the implementation. Can someone explain to me why the voltage on the probe is 0.6 V even if the circuit has no "ON" button attached to it in this moment? I supposed to be off since the gate of PMOSFET should be high but it is not. I am almost sure that I did something wrong in the simulation.

[image]
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe your initial conditions, try applying power to the circuit with a pulse source a microsecond after the simulation starts or play with the options for cap and voltage initial conditions.

Comment: looks like there is a big race condition through there when you first apply the 3.3 because of C3.

Comment: The circuit is taken from this link [link]http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/_detail/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/in-rush-limited-push-button-on-off-toggle-power-switch-circuit.png?id=microcontroller-projects:electronic-circuits:push-button-switch-turn-on:latching-toggle-power-switch, and the explanation seems reasonable to me at least. I also used a pulse source and a controlled switch to simulate a push button  but the cicuit is always on.

Comment: did u not see c2 in that configuration is auto-on?

Comment: According to the website, where other designs are analyzes, the C2 is on auto-off mode when it is tied to 3.3V. The auto-on mode that you suggest is in the link I attached were clearly the switch  on C2 terminal  is tied on GND. Maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: I did manage to get this thing working in LTSPICE, but it is very finicky. esp the choice of diodes.

Comment: What do you mean finicky? Can you suggest some improvement. BTW I was not able to simulate it in LTSPICE. The circuit is always on no matter the connection of C2.